# Varnish policy engine on Ubuntu

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm following the Varnish [docs](https://docs.varnish-software.com/policy-engine/getstarted/) relating to `policy-engine` and am confused how to install it on Ubuntu.  I can't find any repo that seems to have it or any trace of how to install it online.  Has it been renamed or something?  I'm using Varnish 6.0 on Ubuntu.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Policy Engine is a Varnish Enterprise product, you need a subscription to get access to the repositories.

On top of that, it's been discontinued, may I ask where you found a link to that page?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply.  I found the link here - https://docs.varnish-software.com/policy-engine/ - it appears this entire link section needs to be updated/removed as it's pretty confusing.  Also, since that section of the docs is no longer relevant, what is the recommended way or recommended options to do authentication with varnish?

Comment: what I mean is that I know of no link to this page, so you shouldn't be able to click your way to it.